# from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.utils.np_utils'

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to run the following example from keras

but I get this error:

```
C:\Users\ANJALI\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\Minor Project\Minor_HelmetDetection\HelmetDetection>py HelmetDetection.py
2023-11-24 15:00:37.549028: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:113] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\ANJALI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\losses.py:2976: The name tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy instead.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ANJALI\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\Minor Project\Minor_HelmetDetection\HelmetDetection\HelmetDetection.py", line 19, in <module>
    from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.utils.np_utils'
```

I tried updating the libraries, but still no change

Answer (score 1):

Use instead of the line below,

```
import keras.utils.np_utils
```

the code:

```
from keras.utils import to_categorical
```

and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are attempting to import to_categorical from the incorrect module. TensorFlow's to_categorical function is part of tensorflow.keras.utils. Therefore, you need adjust your import statement to:

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
```